# Split a column with dates into multiple columns by month. SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to validate the users logged in based on month. SQL

current df

```
user id             date
P1302              2023-11-01
P1302              2023-10-01
P1302              2023-09-01
P1302              2023-08-01
P1302              2023-07-01
P1302              2023-06-01
P1301              2023-11-01
P1301              2023-10-01
P1301              2023-08-01
P1301              2023-07-01
P1301              2023-06-01
```

expected result

```
user id     Jun     Jul     aug   sep   oct     nov
1302         1       1       1     1     1       1
1301         1       1       1     0     1       1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you care about the year?

Comment: If result will be in only 1 or 0 then can you please try the following query `SELECT 
    user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun',
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul',
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug',
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep',
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct',
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov'
FROM user_dates
GROUP BY user_id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` function with conditional statements `(MONTH(date) = month_number)` to count the occurrences of logins for each user in each month.

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    SUM(MONTH(date) = 6) AS Jun,
    SUM(MONTH(date) = 7) AS Jul,
    SUM(MONTH(date) = 8) AS Aug,
    SUM(MONTH(date) = 9) AS Sep,
    SUM(MONTH(date) = 10) AS Oct,
    SUM(MONTH(date) = 11) AS Nov
FROM 
    user_activity
GROUP BY 
    user_id;
```

**[See this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/C1BKEYq-)**.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach to your problem is to use count over a case expression:

```
select user_id
     , count(case month(dt) = 1 then 1 end) as jan
     , count(case month(dt) = 2 then 1 end) as feb
     , ...
from ...
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
    MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov
FROM your_table
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY user_id;
```